# Reference findViewbyID from Fragment in Non-Fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I have a Fragment class `EchossStampFragment` in which I can directly reference

> .findViewbyId(R.id.mainView)

In my second non-fragment class `EchossMainView` I want to address this View and change its background.

How can I address it in onInitSuccess like so:

```
public void onInitSuccess() {
        // EchossStampActivity.setText("onInitSuccess");
        mainView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

in the `EchossMainView` class?

EchossStampFragment Class

```
public class EchossStampFragment extends Fragment implements EchossStampInterface {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    View myView;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    EchossMainView mainView = null;
    static TextView textView = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_echoss, container, false);
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mainView = (EchossMainView) getView().findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

        // Display Initialization

        DisplayMetrics metric = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metric);
        mainView.init(metric);

        mainView.initEchossMainView(this); // this is where we are passing the current activity as interface

        // Library Initialization for Stamp
        mainView.echossPlatformInit(APIKEY, REGION, LANGUAGE, INDEX);

    }
```

EchossMainView Class

```
public class EchossMainView extends StampBaseView {

    private EchossStampInterface mEchossStampInterface;

    public EchossMainView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EchossMainView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EchossMainView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void onInitSuccess() {
        EchossStampActivity.setText("onInitSuccess");
        mainView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    }
    public void onInitError(String code, String message) {
        EchossStampFragment.setText("onInitError - " + code + " " + message);

    }


    public void onStampSuccess(String stampResult) {
        EchossStampFragment.setText("onStampSuccess - " + stampResult);

    }

    public void onStampError(String code, String message) {
         EchossStampFragment.setText("onStampError - " + code + " " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is EchossMainView and StampBaseView? Assuming they both extend a view, you can call `setBackground()` from within the class itself. If you need to set text to a text view inside them, you might want to consider making a custom ViewGroup or something similar.

Comment: `StampBaseView` is an external 3rd party library. 
I need to address a `mainView` in my xml layout. I can do this from the Fragment but not directly from EchossMainView.

If I just do what you said, the background of the xml tag `mainView` won't change. 
How can I extend the View from the Fragment class to `EchossMainView` Class?

Comment: I don't think you need to. Did you see my answer to this, and have you tried it out yet? I suspect it will work for you.

Comment: I tried it out. `mainView` is a specifc frame in XML layout for which I want to change the background colour. If I just do what you say the XML layout will not know what object to change the colour for.

Comment: but `mainView` is an instance of `EchessMainView` so why wouldn't that work?

Comment: The error message I get is:
`setBackground() in View cannot be applied to (int) `

Comment: Then it's a simple mistake of using it wrong. If you wanna set color, try calling `setBackgroundColor(int)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `EchossMainView` must eventually extend from View, you can call setBackground from within that class itself:

```
public void onInitSuccess() {
    setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Docs for method here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)

Comment: Thank you. Marked your answer as correct.
On a different note, would you know how to call the `onInitSuccess` method from the `EchossMainView` Class in the `EchossStampFragment` Class?

Comment: If it were a public method, you could just say `mainView.onInitSuccess()` inside the fragment class. @Stefan

Comment: I appreciate your help! Solved!